# Cannot Resolve Symbol ListItem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to parse json to recyclerview in a fragment but i'm getting "Cannot Resolve Symbol ListItem " Error in loadData method !! i don't know what to do.
 please help me

Here is my code :

```
private void loadData() {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i =0;i<array.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
   -->**Cannot Resolve Symbol ListItem **    ListItem item = new ListItem(        
                            o.getString("_id"),
                            o.getString("store_textposition")
                    );
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQuene = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQuene.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Whats' the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show enough to diagnose your problem, but it sounds like you failed to import the type. If you did import the type, then the `import` directive would have the same error, and that would mean that you have a classpath problem.